# Capture ajax events inside in an iframe from parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

How can we capture an ajax event inside an iframe completely from parent window scope? either using jquery or normal javascript?

like, the code in parent window is ,

```
<body>
<iframe class="childframe" src="http://localhost/ajax-page.php"></iframe>
</body>
```

and the ajax-page.php contains,

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $.ajax({
    url:'http://localhost/',
    complete: function(data){
       alert('ajax complete inside iframe');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

I want to trigger a function in parent window when the ajax event is completed inside iframe.

Answer (score 0):

If parent and child-frame are on the same domain (both localhost in this case, so I assume they do):

```
window.parent.myFunctionInParent();
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, my try is to look from parent to child.

Answer (score 0):

use http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

[Example:](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/)

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});

<p><a class='iframe' href="http://wikipedia.com">Outside Webpage (Iframe)</a></p>
```